# CSS layout issue with TABLE in DIV

Tags: html, css, html-table

Why doesn't the `"aaaaaaaaa..."` go to a new line and go out of `div`?

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    background: #888888;
    color: white;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
}

#container li {
    list-style: none;
}

#container td {
    padding-right: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>

<div id="container">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>one</td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>two</li>
                    <li>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: @Matt Indeed, though I'm more concerned about the effort that was put into [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342742/how-can-i-reset-the-tabbar-in-an-iphone-application) by Matthew Frederick.

Comment: @Matt I take back everything I said ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is css3 feature **word wrap**: http://www.css3.info/preview/word-wrap/

This have some browser compatibility issues but I think if you are determined to use such long words, this is an option.

This is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/VXgdS/2/

Comment: This won't work inside a table though (as far as I know anyway)

Comment: Yeah it doesn't works inside a table. @Joaquin why do you need such long words. I can't think of a reason why you want to put such long words in one li tag!

Comment: Because it's a comment. I use three <li>: for comment author, for comment text and for comment time. The table is for avatar in the left and in the right comment author/text/time. Any idea for do the same in another way?

Comment: Just don't use tables. Make 2 divs that float:left. One with your picture and then other one with comment text and comment time. You will then be able to use word-wrap / word-break.

Answer (score 1):

If there aren't any spaces in your word then your table will expand to fit the word. There isn't much you can do about that (not with css anyway). Word wrap only works with actual word (i.e. with spaces in them).

A solution that will work for you though is to use the `&shy;` (soft hyphen)

```
<li>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&shy;aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</li>
```

will break in the middle. It will only break there if it needs to - if it doesn't fit in the parent container.

There are a number of other solutions available, most of them are unreliable cross-browser or break your design:

The word break tag : `<wbr>` is unreliable. 
The overflow CSS statement will either break your design (overflow:auto) or hide content (overflow:hidden)

So basically, no easy solution. Soft-hyphen will work best if you can use it.

You could look into [hyphenator](http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/), a way to automate work breaks like that on your website.

For your edit, if it's a variable then I would definitely with hyphenator.

Comment: The text is a var, is not a defined text. So there isn't any solutions?